# supported functions in matlab code generation

Tags: c++, matlab, code-generation

I am trying to find out what functions in matlab are supported when you are trying to do code generation.

Right now I am getting the following: Failed to eliminate a use of the MATLAB function 'real'. For non-simulation builds, uses of unsupported MATLAB functions are eliminated if they do not affect function outputs.

This is on a line like so:

```
enhanced_img = zeros(N);
enhanced_img = real(fft_2d(temp3));
```

Is it true that I can't use a simple function like real(), and will have to list it as extrinsic, or am I doing somethign else wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can find the list of supported functions here: 
http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2011a/toolbox/eml/ug/bsud5f4.html

To view this same documentation in your MATLAB Help browser, type the following in your command line: 
web([docroot '/toolbox/eml/ug/bq1h2z5-1.html'])

'real' and 'fft2' are both supported for code generation with MATLAB Coder. You are using fft_2d - I assume that's probably some custom function you wrote. You have to ensure the code written within that function is all supported for code generation.

Hope this helps. 
-Arvind -- MATLAB Coder Product Manager -- MathWorks